# MySQL illegal mix of collations, ASCII to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I have a MySQL 8.0 table like this, which is UTF-8 apart from one field, which holds an ASCII UUID that doesn't need UTF-8 overhead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `things` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `things_uuid_unique` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and I'm getting query failures like this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations
(ascii_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
(SQL: select * from `things` where (`uuid` = 1abb9e11-4f00-4904-988e-233a3c0ce411) limit 1)
```

My connection is using `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, the other fields, table, and database are using the same collation, and my scripts themselves are also UTF-8, though that makes no practical difference here since it's just ASCII. This particular query uses a string literal containing only 7-bit ASCII chars, not a field name or variable.

I don't understand why this fails, since (unlike ISO-8859 charsets), ASCII is UTF-8 compatible; there is no ASCII string that is not also a valid UTF-8 string, so why wouldn't this be coercible? Is it something to do with `ci` vs `bin`? I can't solve this by switching the connection to ASCII because the real queries use multiple fields, some of which are UTF-8.

I know that I can force the comparison using:

```
select * from `things` where (`uuid` = BINARY '1abb9e11-4f00-4904-988e-233a3c0ce411')
```

But that also seems unnecessary, and not something I've needed to do before, in the same circumstances. I guess worst case I could switch the UUID field to UTF-8, but that offends my developer sensibilities!

It's doubly frustrating as I know I've used this pattern successfully many times before!

Comment: Hi there. I don't have time right to test anything, but I suspect the issue is that MySQL is wanting to coerce the literal into the collation of the column. In that direction, even though in your case there wouldn't be any data loss, if the character set has to be coerced as well, then there _could_ be data loss going from UTF-8 to ASCII. Swap the two character sets and collation and it might could work (just as a test, though). Still, since (as you also pointed out) all ASCII is also UTF-8, why not just use UTF-8 charset for that columnand UTF-8_BIN for the collation?

Comment: Indeed, I could try to shove a UTF-8 value in that field and I would expect it to fail. The same could be said about UTF-8 `ci` vs `bin` collations. UTF-8 has a whole load of processing overhead that's really not needed for simple ASCII fields, and it eats index space too. As I said though, I've done this many times before without issue – this project has been doing this for a couple of years, but only just recently has this error started happening. I'm wondering if there's been some recent change in MySQL that's caused it.

Comment: You did need to quote the 36-character literal.

Comment: That's just how MySQL displays errors; it is quoted in the original query.

Comment: Synchro: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make regarding UTF-8 `ci` vs `bin`, but either way, those are collations, not character sets, so there is no issue of data loss. And sure, non-binary UTF-8 is certainly more complex than non-binary ASCII. But, binary is just that: binary, hence no linguistic rules. There shouldn't be much, if any, overhead for `utf8_bin` _collation_. There might be _some_ overhead for the `utf8_mb4` _charset_ regarding determination of valid byte sequences, but that shouldn't have a noticeable impact here. (cont.)

Comment: I can't say about index space without testing though I wouldn't expect it to take more space for just ASCII characters (though I seem to recall either PostgreSQL or MySQL maybe reserving the full max 4 bytes per character, though that was based on possibly poorly worded documentation and not on any empirical evidence). Regardless of any of that stuff, it's possible that there was a configuration change or something that made it stop working given that here is an example of the code you posted working on MySQL 8.0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a1d4c9546667c780625a60dcd3cf8f9

Comment: Thanks for trying! I'm wondering if this might possibly be a Laravel bug, where it is perhaps using the wrong connection charset in some particular circumstances, or something similarly odd. The query I posted is one that is actually generated by Laravel – the first query of a `firstOrCreate` call. In particular I've noticed that it gives this error when comparing but not when updating the value, even though MySQL is going to have to convert a literal UTF-8 value into an ASCII value either way.

Comment: The `ci`/`bin` thing was along the lines of running into unique index problems when strings only differ in case, in which case the collation makes a big difference.

Comment: `ascii_bin` (and any other binary or case-sensitive) is not suitable collation for UUID because its value is not case-dependent (it is treated as hexadecimal value, not as string value).

Comment: Not true. I’m in control of both generating and consuming my own UUIDs. A binary collation works just fine for that, and is the most efficient as it requires no transformations at all.

Comment: @Akina : Given that Synchro is in control of the values coming in (hence can enforce upper-casing all values), a binary collation is definitely the way to go as there is no need for the complex linguistic rules built into non-binary collations, especially Unicode collations. Synchro: just FYI, now that more than 1 person (outside of yourself) has commented, we will only get notifications of your replies if you include our `@` name in your reply (and you can only do one of those per comment).

Comment: *I’m in control of both generating and consuming my own UUIDs.* Either it is case-insensitive (see standard) or it is not UUID but only UUID-like value.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I know. But my comment was addressed to OP only so I have not added somebody else to the participants to be notified. Question/answer author is notified anycase, not depends of his nick prefixed with `@` mentioned in a comment.

Comment: @Akina Regarding case-insensitivity, if all hex characters `A`-`F` are forced to upper-case on the way in, and all comparisons are done using only upper-cased literals and variables, then isn't the operation (not the value) case-insensitive since there can't be any changes in outcome due to variations in casing? I don't believe the standard is referring to only ever using a specifically case-insensitive comparison. And, I do understand that your comment wasn't directed to me, so my advice regarding notifications was really only directed at Synchro. I apologize for not being clearer about that.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky *my advice regarding notifications was really only directed at Synchro* The author of commented object is notified anycase. Moreover, if you add author's nick by such way into your comment it will be striped from the text in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I am doing everything correctly, and I'm not insane! This problem is [a bug in MySQL 8.0.22](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101575) (also [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101346)) that is apparently [fixed in 8.0.23](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html). Unfortunately I'm using Percona server which has not yet released its 8.0.23 derivative.

Comment: Good job finding those bug reports. Hopefully the fix navigates its way to your server sooner than later :-)